# How to differentiate between email and chat documents in lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'm trying to extract all emails and chat history of a person from his nsf file (lotus notes). I'm using Notes.jar. All the entries in nsf files are documents. Is there a way to identify which document is email and which document is chat. There is an item named "Form" which is used to identify mails (memo), meeting invites (appointment). The problem I face here is both email and chat has form type "Memo".
Kindly suggest me a way to differentiate between email and chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right: Both kind of documents have form `Memo`.
Chat- Transcripts in addition have an item `$IMTranscript` that identifies them.

I found out this fact, using the Icon- Column of the All Documents- view `($All)`, as Chat- transcripts have different icons in that view. Here is the relevant part of that formula:

```
@IsAvailable($IMTranscript) & @LowerCase(IMoriginator) = @LowerCase(IMowner); 
"ChatTranscriptMe.gif";
@IsAvailable($IMTranscript); "Chat_transcript_icon.gif";
```

Comment: Thanks Link. I tried with $IMTranscript and it is working for me.